# C++: Not recognizing char value when evaluating if statement

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, char, comparison

Every time I run this code, for whatever reason, it calls all functions regardless of whether the `if` statement evaluates to true

```
int main()
 {
 char StartUnit, EndUnit;
  double StartVal = 0, EndVal = 0;
  double CalcVal = 0;
  static double result = 0;

  //Receive user input

  cout << "Please enter the unit which you would like to convert from: ";
  cin >> StartUnit;
  cout << "What is your initial value?: ";
  cin >> StartVal;
  cout << "Please enter the unit which you would like to convert to: ";
  cin >> EndUnit;

  //Step 1: Convert input to celsius

  if (StartUnit = 'f')
  {
  CalcVal = FarCel(StartVal);
  }

  if (StartUnit = 'k')
  {
  CalcVal = KelCel(StartVal);
  }

  if (StartUnit = 'r')
  {
  CalcVal = RakCel(StartVal);
  }

  //Step 2: Conver celsius to desired value

  cout << CalcVal;

  return 0;
}
```

When I output CalcVal, no matter what, it seems to run through all three functions. It doesn't matter what I type, r, c, f, they all evaluate the same. Could I have some advice on where I'm going wrong?

---

Solved: Question's answer is that `==` is used for comparison, my `if` test used `=`

Comment: If your professor couldn't immediately spot the obvious bug, and an explanation, as you claimed, you really need to find a new professor. The one you've got is completely incompetent.

Comment: Turn up the warning level of your compiler enough and odds are good it will scream bloody blue murder at you for the ==/= mix up. Level 4 in Visual Studio and adding -Wall -Wextra to the g++ command line should do the job.

Comment: this question has some answer, please select one as the accept answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is debatable. The compiler on the other hand should absolutely warn about this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to assign the values (=), instead of checking them (==). Also you should use `else if` blocks, for better reading.

Comment: That's what it was - thank you so much! Easy oversight, beginner. And apparently my professor is, too :P

Answer (score 0):

All your if-statements *assing* (`=`), rather than *comparing* (`==`).

So, change this:

```
if (StartUnit = 'f')
```

to this:

```
if (StartUnit == 'f')
```

and act similar for the rest of the if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are three features of C++ that together combine to produce this problem:

1. In C, C++, and many related language, there is a difference between `=` (a single equals sign) and `==` (two equals signs together). The first is an assignment, the second is a comparison. `StartUnit = 'f'` means "Set `StartUnit` to the value `'f'`"; you meant to use `StartUnit == 'f'`.
2. In a lot of languages, and assignment is actually an expression and also has a value. In this case, it's the value assigned, so `StartUnit = 'f'` means "Set `StartUnit` to `f`, and also return the value `'f'`". Since it's in an `if` statement, that both sets `StartUnit` and does `if ('f')`.
3. When an `if` statement or other boolean operation looks at an `int`, `float`, `char`, etc., it checks if they are non-zero. Since `'f'` isn't the Nul byte `'\x00'` (and neither is `'0'`), it evaluates as true and the `if` statement body is executed.

Since all of these `if` statements work the same way, this happens for all of them and all the functions run.

---

You might also want to use `else` clauses, or even a `switch` statement. A bunch of `if` statements, one after the other, looks like none, any, or all of them could run. Since you want one and only one to happen, you should use `else` blocks or a switch statement.